# Hibernate sequence creation with SQL script?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sequence

In my Spring Boot app, I want to use sequence for each entity as shown below:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="author_gen", sequenceName = "author_seq")
    private Long id;
     
    ...
     
}
```

There are different kind of usages regarding to sequence generation on database side. So;

**1)** Is this implementation above enough to create a sequence on database when using Hibernate only?

**2)** In addition to the annotation above, do I also need a manual sequence creation on database side when I use Flyway or `schema.sql` in the Spring Boot app?

Comment: Does anybody else ever used sequence in Hibernate?

Comment: @NathanHughes Good point that you mentioned, thanks. At this step, I am confused. I think I should use both of them for dev and prod.

Comment: @NathanHughes As a result, would it be good --> **1.** to define all of the database objects e.g. sequence, index, etc. and then generate SQL script from these definitions and use this script as an initial or migration script?

Comment: **2.** How do you switch between dev and prod for this schema creation? I mean, what is your `ddl-auto` setting and when do you change it (for example when switching to prod)? Could you give an example scenario or steps?

Comment: I will use multiple application.properties but even so, could you give a little bit detail? For example you may use Hibernate map creation for dev and flyway for prod, etc?

Comment: Then, whic annotations do you use in your Entities? Id, Entity, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany..., Index, Sequence, etc?

Answer (score 1):

yes this will create a sequence for you.

You just need to inform some things in jpa properties.

Below are the properties of my app:

spring:

jpa:

```
show-sql: true

properties:

  hibernate:

   default_schema: controle_financeiro #if you have a default schema, if not you need to put it in the schema annotation = "your sequence schema" 

   auto_quote_keyword: true

    ddl-auto: create #!!MORE IMPORTANT!! here you inform to create the mapped entities

    format_sql: false #if you need formatted sql code

database: postgresql

database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect #plataform

open-in-view: false

generate-ddl: true #if you need the generated DDL code, it will appear in the console
```

My sequences created with JPA

[Sequences on DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vFWV.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHcMr.png)

[Another way to create sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSHzn.png)

Comment: Thanks amigo, voted up. Actually I am confused regarding to creating database elements using Hibernate/JPA or SQL script. For example, when using Flyway, we disable `ddl-auto`, and then, is there any need to use `@SequenceGenerator()` except from informing the developer about that a sequence is used for that table?

Comment: There are a few other ways to use sequences in hibernate.
The current way we are doing it, yes it is necessary, because strange things start to happen, like sequences being generated with negative values.

Comment: I added another way to generate sequences in the answer